# Math isn't a constructor but it has

Tags: javascript, constructor

Here's a trick question i can't figure out. As I read from MDN we cannot create instance from `Math`. Running `new Math()` will produce an exception `Math is not a constructor`. But Math has own property inside `Math.constructor`. Yes it's `Object` type but we could run it `Math.constructor()`. But even we redefine it by exec `Math.constructor = Function.constructor` it also throw an exception.

Now I had some suppositions in my mind:

- constructor contains a hidden property and browser engine refuses invoke it.
- constructor interpreted into special c++ object in browser engine which has index in "TypeError:not a constructor" collection.

Could someone answer me thoroughly why constructor exists but I cannot create an instance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every object has a constructor, doesn't mean you can create new instances of object literals etc. The answer to this question is probably just *"because the spec says so"*.

Comment: @AndreiZhamoida [you can read the language specification anytime you want to :)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)

Comment: `Math` is an object. This object must have been constructed. Each object *inherits* the prototype-methods of it's constructor (in this case: Object). `Object.prototype.constructor = Object`

Comment: Functions are objects which are callable.  Math is not a function. Its contructor was the global object Object, not Function.

Comment: `typeof Math.constructor` is `function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote myself, the answer is

> *because the spec says so*

and the [spec says](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8)

> **The Math Object**
>
> The Math object is a single object that has some named properties,
>   some of which are functions.
>
> The value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of the Math object is
>   the standard built-in Object prototype object (15.2.4). The value of
>   the `[[Class]]` internal property of the Math object is "Math".
>
> **The Math object does not have a `[[Construct]]` internal property; it is
>   not possible to use the Math object as a constructor with the new
>   operator.**
>
> The Math object does not have a `[[Call]]` internal property; it is not possible to invoke the Math object as a function.

Every object in javascript has a constructor, and `Math` is an object, hence it has a constructor, that doesn't mean you can create new instances of it, it's the same as

```js
var Math = {
  random : true,
  max    : false
}

new Math(); // epic fail, not a constructor (function)
```

Comment: Hmm, I think it's definitely something that I was looking for. Could I say what this hidden in browser engine realization according to spec? Will it correct?

Comment: @AndreiZhamoida - Sure, that's it ?

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor:

> All objects inherit a constructor property from their prototype:
>
> ```
> var o = {};
> o.constructor === Object; // true
>
> var a = [];
> a.constructor === Array; // true
> ```

`Math` is just a predefined global object, therefore:

```
Math.constructor === Object;
```

---

Though very seldom used, `var obj = new Object()` is valid javascript. `var obj = {}` is more common and shorter; use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Math is an object similar to usual objects that programmer creates via new operator.

Pseudo code is:

```
var Math = new Object();
Math.E = 2.71;
Math.PI = 3.14;
...
```

That's why

```
Math.constructor === Object; // true. As for usual objects that we create via new operator.
Math.__proto__ === Object.prototype; //ture. As for usual objects that we create via new operator.
Object.getPrototypeOf(Math) === Object.prototype; //true. As for usual objects that we create via new operator.
Math.prototype === undefined; // ture. As for usual objects that we create via new operator.
```

Hence, prototype chaine is the following here:
Math -> Object.prototype -> null

Compare the above with for example standard Date object.
Date is a function (not a pure object that is created via new operator as above).

Pseudo code is:

```
function Date() {
...
}
```

That's why

```
Date.constructor === Function; // true. As for usual functions that we create.
Date.__proto__ === Function.prototype; //ture. As for usual functions that we create.
Object.getPrototypeOf(Date) === Function.prototype; //true. As for usual functions that we create.
Date.prototype !== Date.__proto__; // Date.prototype is a prototype for new Date() but Date.__proto__ is a prototype for Date itself.
```

Hence, prototype chaine is the following here:
Date-> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null